# Convert percent to decimal: (/ PERCENT 100)

Tags: math

To convert from percent to decimal:  divide by 100, and remove the "%" sign.

The snippet `(/ PERCENT 100)` yields a seemingly unexpected result.  E.g., Converting 50% to a decimal should yield `0.5`; however, `(/ 50 100)` returns `0`.

Tentative workaround pending an answer:  `(* PERCENT .01)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your workaround tells the whole story:

```
(/ 1 2) ;=> 0
(/ 1.0 2) ;=>0.5
```

With integers, emacs does integer arithmetic, with floats it does floating-point arithmetic.

---

See the Elisp manual, node [Arithmetic Operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Arithmetic-Operations.html):

> Except for `%`, each of these functions accepts both integer and
> floating-point arguments, and returns a floating-point number if any
> argument is floating point.

And, for `/`:

> If all the arguments are integers, the result is an integer,
> obtained by rounding the quotient towards zero after each division.

See also node [Numeric Conversions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Numeric-Conversions.html), for info about explicitly converting among numeric types.